# SQL Queries - llf function in Access;

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have looked up a lot on Google but can't seem to adapt them. 
I'm running a query from my tables. And there are some fields that I want to use under following conditions.
[query picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7vL6z.jpg)

1. If QShipped = 0, If QBackordered = 0,
   Use QOrdered
2. If QShipped = 0, If QBackordered > 0,
   Use QShipped – QBackordered  (subtraction)
3. If QShipped > 0, If QBackordered = 0,
   Use QShipped – QOrdered
4. If QShipped > 0, If QBackordered > 0,
   Use QBackordered

I think that I'm using `llf` or `switch` function but I'm clueless beyond that.

I will be responsive as possible as I can!

> > Syntax error (missing operator in query expression. THANK YOU SO MUCH!
> >     [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7vL6z.jpg)

Comment: Step 2 looks wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

access has something called switch it works like case in standard SQL

```
 Switch(
    QShipped = 0 and QBackordered = 0, QOrdered,
    QShipped = 0 and QBackordered > 0, QShipped – QBackordered,
    QShipped > 0 and QBackordered = 0, QShipped – QOrdered,
    QShipped > 0 and QBackordered > 0, QBackordered
 ) AS my_column_name
```

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Switch-Function-d750c10d-0c8e-444c-9e63-f47504f9e379

Comment: If you are still online, I'm terribly sorry but would you be able to take a look at the syntax error that I have? Thank you

Comment: @JohnTipton -- it looks fine, to test just comment out lines to find out the one with the problem

Comment: thanks will do :) Thank you so much again! sorry for bothering you